# Browser shows IIS Error Messages with WebSphere error messages below

Tags: iis, websphere, errordocument, custom-errors

I am working on an environment (external) where IIS is the web server and WebSphere is the application server. I have noticed that the error messages (Ex. 403, 404) show both IIS error messages as well as what the application returns through WebSphere.

I am not able to replicate this in a local environment. I can either get it to show one or the other using existingResponse.

I want to know how the external environment set this up and how I would make it only show the IIS error message.

Comment: I've never seen that before. If you look at the html source of the error page. Does is have to separate opening html tags? So WebSphere in just appending it's html to the existing one, or is it valid html with where WebSpere inject its html at some spot?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I didn't think to look at that. That is a good idea. I will check. I was thinking it was something to do with the WAS IIS plugin, but did not see any reference in the plugin-cfg.xml file. ** I will check this tomorrow when I have access to the env.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf WebSphere is appending it's html to the existing IIS page. You find the <html> tags for the WAS error message right after the IIS html section.

Comment: I've no idea about WebSphere and how it integrates with IIS. Are there any http modules set up in the web.config. They could be used to append any additional html to the response.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much either. I believe a virtual directory is setup which uses a plugin that configures the WebSphere applications to forward through the IIS site. I checked the main plugin and couldn't see anything too relevant. I checked the web.config on several levels (base, app level, and virtual dir level [plugin]) which don't have any http modules.